# Should we convert our tag wikis to Spanish?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Long ago we converted most of our tag names to Spanish, but most of our tag wikis are still in English.  Do we want to convert these to Spanish as well?

Comment: I'm not sure what the best way is, but I do think it's important to keep a version of the wikis in English (so that they are accessible to new Spanish language learners). The tag names should be in Spanish to avoid confusion with the corresponding concepts in the English grammar (that, often, are subtly different).

Answer (score 4):

Instead of excluding speakers of either language to the functionality bonus added by tag wikis and wikis, I suggest changing both to include both languages in each.

Example:

Spain/España which would show up for a search typed in either language.

Comment: To be clear, [tag:spain] is already a synonym to [tag:espana], and this is not what I'm asking about. I'm asking about the tag wikis. Although they could be in English and Spanish, if that is what you're suggesting.

Comment: Yes, each word has an equivalent in the other language.  So I suggest including both in everything, including in the code, as well as the tag wikis.

Answer (score 2):

I would volunteer to do work with the tags, but I would at least ask not tot have to re do it.

Recently I spent a lot of time completing some tags that had no description, and completed *excerpts* and *description* in Spanish, because they were Spanish tags. With the English version of each tag still present, I didn't think that the same tag had tho have text in both languages.

My proposal is:

- Tag with format: tag name in Spanish *slash* tag name in English, such as "Vocabulario/vocabulary". Tag name in Spanish should have accents.
- Get rid of duplicates (If we are lucky this means deleting the tags in English, that seems not to being used anyway, and just alter the name of the tags in Spanish via moderator privileges).
- Really brief excerpt in bot languages. Spanish first, then English.
- Extended description for the tag, Spanish first, then English. No need to include captions "Spanish/English" to save space.

If we can agree to something, and request the accent feature for tag names, [that I know is ready](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/373/5481), I will start dedicating some time here and there to complete this job.

Comment: It seems we have just had accent marks enabled for our tags! YAY!

Comment: @Flimzy, great news! I would love to do some work on tags. What is the best way of collaborating on completing tags right now?

Answer (score 1):

I think the text of the tag wiki should be in Spanish first, with English following.  Maybe there should be a note in English telling the user to scroll down.

Any volunteers to start translating?  I'm ready to volunteer, at the risk of making some mistakes.  My Spanish is good, but not perfect.