# Deberían nuestras etiquetas llevar acentos?

Tags: discusión, petición-de-funcionalidad, estado-completado

Leyendo algunas de las meta-preguntas (si se debe permitir "Spanglish" en las preguntas, o sobre "editing misspellings", por ejemplo) y dado que cuando accedo a este sitio (probablemente al igual que otros usuarios) no tengo acceso a un teclado donde me sea facil poner acentos, llevo un rato preguntandome sobre la importancia de los mismos a la hora de aprender a escribir correctamente en castellano y su uso en este sitio.

Creo que nuestras etiquetas estan en *Espanyol*, pero no llevan acentos (veo *traduccion*, *discusion*, *mexico*, *espana*, ...).

Quiza escribir con acentos no siempre es facil o posible (no lo es para mi ahora), pero en algunas respuestas es critico usarlos y si vamos a intentar ayudar a quienes hacen uso de este sitio a hablar y escribir correctamente, no deberiamos ser consistentes con las normas ortograficas y poner acentos en nuestras etiquetas?

No estoy propoponiendo que cada pregunta y respuesta deban llevar la ortografia **perfecta** (salvo en aquellos casos donde sea necesario para la explicacion), pero creo las etiquetas deberian. En la medida de lo posible, si este sito puede escribir correctamente una palabra, creo que deberia. Es casi como ver una falta de ortografia en la portada de tu libro de gramatica.

Ademas, a base de ver la palabras correctametne escritas se reforzaria el aprendizaje de los usuarios.

Comment: Por lo que veo, esto ya está implementado. Le añado pues la etiqueta de "status-completed".

Answer (score 3):

Cuando empezó a funcionar este sitio las etiquetas no podían llevar tildes u otros caracteres especiales. Puedes leer la petición para implementarlo [Add non-Latin character set support for tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135929/add-non-latin-character-set-support-for-tags).

Parece que ya está terminado, habría que pedir que lo activen en este sitio.

Comment: Entendia que era una posibilidad que esa funcionalidad no estuviese disponible, o incluso que las reglas del foro lo prohibiesen o que obligasen a que las etiquetas estuviesen en ingles, que es el idioma del foro (que no es el caso, porque las etiquetas de meta estan en ingles pero las del sition princial no), pero si ya se puede yo no lo dudaria, salvo que alguien vea una razon de peso para no hacerlo.

Comment: Estamos de acuerdo en que es buena idea? Alguien puede preveer algun problema? Quien puede hacer la peticion?

Comment: [Sorry, I can decipher Spanish but not write it] Stack Exchange staff can enable tag names with accents. A moderator should request it. On [french.se] we've had tag names with accents for a few months; there were a few bugs initially but now they're working well. We always provide a non-accented version as a synonym for the sake of users who cannot type accented letters easily. @Diego

Comment: @Gilles, Thanks!! I actually didn't think about the problems of trying to type a tag name when you don't have special characters... I was expecting this meta-question to get more answers/discussion or votes. I'm not sure how many users support this idea, but still I think it should be done. I think the site has mechanism to vote on things, although I have never been able to participate in one... Lets see if this attracts the attention of a moderator who can request it. Thanks also for your best effort deciphering Spanish.