# Missing English explanations in some tag wikis

Tags: discusión, soporte, etiquetas

The consensus [in this related post](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/352/6782) is that all tag wikis should come with English explanations, as well as Spanish ones (if necessary).

However, the following tags are missing English descriptions:

- [vocabulario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulario)
- [pronunciacion](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciacion)
- [adjetivos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adjetivos)
- [numeros](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numeros)
- [espana](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/espana)
- [expresion](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresion)
- [dialects](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialects)
- [nombres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nombres)
- [formalidad](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formalidad)
- [america-latina](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/america-latina)
- probably a few more (I only checked the first two pages)

I don't want to clog up the suggested edit queue with a flood of suggestions, and I don't know enough Spanish to translate most of these properly anyway.

Could these and other problem tags be cleaned up to include English explanations, so those of us who haven't learned enough Spanish to understand them yet can make sense of them?

Comment: I edited those tags to add English definitions. Are there any others you want me to address next? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I actually think that there is no consensus about including both languages in every tag. The question you linked has two proposals, but **I can't find any *best practices* or suggestions from moderators**.

First, tags should be almost self-explanatory, even if the have a title and body. Second, I think that we have duplicate tags, for English and Spanish (for example, *vocabulario* with hundreds of uses, and vocabulary, with none). Third, I made my [own proposal](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/373/5481) to have tag names with accents.

Also, the other day I went into *berserker mode* and completed a lot of tags (so probably I clogged up the suggested edit queue, as you said). I did that in only one language, because the tag name was only in one language. If we can agree to do either one or the other, I wouldn't mind completing tags. Also, I'm close to get *moderator tools* privileges, so if we agree to leave tags as "vocabulario/vocabulary" I wouldn't mind deleting the ones we are no longer using a editing the right ones.

So, to add up, I wouldn't mind giving some attention and time to the tags, but I would hate to do useless work. If we can agree on *what to do* with the tags first, I will dedicate some more time now and then to complete them.

Comment: Really? I don't see anyone objecting to English tag wikis in the linked meta post, and both answers there support having at least some English within tag wikis. (If you're still not convinced, it makes it incredibly difficult for people who are still learning Spanish like me to tag questions correctly, since I can't make any bit of sense out of the Spanish descriptions.)

Comment: @Doorknob, That's the thing. You shouldn't need to read a description to fully understand a tag. The tag should be self-explanatory. When you create a new question and you are tagging it, do you choose in a list of descriptions or do you tag a concept/tag name in the text field? Also, I don't object to English tags. I just want to know if we duplicate tags for English and Spanish or if we duplicate content in them **for sure** before doing any work. Also, that question you linked has no accepted answer. Administrators should indicate the guidelines.

Comment: Then what's the point of having a wiki in the first place? One of the main goals of tag wikis is to provide usage guidance, and these completely fail at that aspect. When I look for the right tag to use, I do indeed often read the wikis to make sure I'm tagging correctly (which is especially important considering the Spanish tag names that I might not understand). As for the linked meta post, just because the OP hasn't accepted the answer doesn't mean there isn't a clear community consensus.

Comment: @Doorknob, I understand, but I don't see that clear consensus or administrators/community managers guidelines. Could you point me to it, please? I'm not trying to leave anybody out, but I have done a lot of work completing tags that now needs to be redone. I don't want to be doing a lot of work again if is not going to stay for good.

Comment: @Diego as you said there is no consensus about including both languages, I check in french and they have the tag description in french, but in German they have the description in German and English, it's seem the user have to take the initiative.

Comment: @Diego I don't see any comments or answers that oppose to including both English and Spanish tag wikis. (Which is basically the definition of a unanimous consensus.)

Comment: @EmilioGort, I mostly meant consensus among Spanish site. We could do pretty much what we wanted, despite whatever other StackExchange sites are doing. It is just, what works for us? I asked some time ago about the accents in the tag names. If that is ready I wouldn't mind unifying tags. I just don't want to rewrite them again.

Comment: @Doorknob, so, could you explain me what the format should look like for the tag, excerpt and body, please?

Comment: @Doorknob, could we not leave this in the air like most of the meta posts? I would love to start working on this, but I need to know how when I edit the tags. Should we create a new meta question with updated _best practices_ for tags and abide to that?

Comment: @Doorknob, [trying my best to understand the consensus](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/a/1394/5481) to start working on this issue. Nevertheless, it seems that most meta-topics fall into oblivion before reaching a practical solution... Could we attract some attention into this again?

Comment: @Doorknob, so, It seems I was wrong and moderator tools don't give me the _unlimited powers_ I thought I would have. Nevertheless, I have already edited some tags to add both Spanish and English and they got adopted, so if the list you have in your question is representative of the work that needs to be done I'll start with those. Thanks.